# Throttle testng

Tags: java, testng

I am running testng in multi-threaded mode with @DataProvider(name = "blah", parallel = true)

My tests are calling a production service and I would like to limit the number of requests per second. Is there a way to throttle testng?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind importing Guava or if you already use it, you could simply introduce [a `RateLimiter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html). In other words, [in your test](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava-tests/test/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiterTest.java?r=f8d47319ee710ecbf55eab44016a8f3355c6d7b1), instead of:

```
@Test public void test() { runYourTest(); }
```

you do:

```
//10 tests per second, for example:
private static final RateLimiter rateLimiter = RateLimiter.create(10.0);

@Test(dataProvider="blah")
public void test() { rateLimiter.acquire(); runYourTest(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say throttle the test number of threads.
http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-running 
See this documentation on explanation on how to do it both in XML and @Annotation

Comment: Can you be more specific? I don't see any mentions of throttling in the documentation.

Comment: That defines the number of threads - but it does not limit the frequency at which the tests are run. So that won't limiting the tests to 5 per seconds, for example...

Answer (score 0):

Most people use [Browsermob Proxy](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy) to do that, using the `PUT /proxy/[port]/limit` API command, but the solution @assylias suggested looks pretty awesome also.